# Email multiple recipients Python

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to email multiple recipients using the pyton script below. I've searched the forum for answers, but have not been able to implement any of them correctly. If anyone has a moment to review my script and spot/resolve the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my script, I gather my issue is in the 'sendmail' portion, but can't figure out how to fix it:

```
gmail_user = "sender@email.com"
gmail_pwd = "sender_password"
recipients = ['recipient1@email.com','recipient2@email.com']

def mail(to, subject, text, attach):
   msg = MIMEMultipart()
   msg['From'] = gmail_user
   msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
   msg['Subject'] = subject

   msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

   part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
   part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
   Encoders.encode_base64(part)
   part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
           'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
   msg.attach(part)

   mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.starttls()
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
   mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
   mailServer.close()

mail("recipient1@email.com, recipient2@email.com",
   "Subject",
   "Message",
   "attchachment")
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Best,

Matt

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: No error, just would only send to the first recipient. Adding the [] brackets around the recipients allowed it to read the list correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be more like

```
mail(["recipient1@email.com", "recipient2@email.com"],
   "Subject",
   "Message", 
   "attchachment")
```

You already have a array of recipients declared,that too globally,You can use that without passing it as an argument to `mail`.

Comment: or just `mail(recipients, ...)` since he already defined the list above the `def` for mail. (and it doesn't matter what he passes in there, because he ignores the 'to' param in the mail method).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm. The help is much appreciated.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran He does use the `to` field further down in the method.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this bit of code to do exactly what you want. If you find a bug let me know (I've tested it and it works):

```
import email as em
import smtplib as smtp
import os

ENDPOINTS = {KEY: 'value@domain.com'}


class BoxWriter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def dispatch(self, files, box_target, additional_targets=None, email_subject=None, body='New figures'):
        """
        Send an email to multiple recipients

        :param files: list of files to send--requires full path
        :param box_target: Relevant entry ENDPOINTS dict
        :param additional_targets: other addresses to send the same email
        :param email_subject: optional title for email
        """

        destination = ENDPOINTS.get(box_target, None)
        if destination is None:
            raise Exception('Target folder on Box does not exist')

        recipients = [destination]
        if additional_targets is not None:
            recipients.extend(additional_targets)

        subject = 'Updating files'
        if email_subject is not None:
            subject = email_subject

        message = em.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart()
        message['From'] = 'user@domain.com'
        message['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
        message['Date'] = em.Utils.formatdate(localtime=True)
        message['Subject'] = subject

        message.attach(em.MIMEText.MIMEText(body + '\n' +'Contents: \n{0}'.format('\n'.join(files))))

        for f in files:
            base = em.MIMEBase.MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            base.set_payload(open(f, 'rb').read())
            em.Encoders.encode_base64(base)
            base.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(os.path.basename(f)))
            message.attach(base)

        conn = smtp.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        un = 'user@gmail.com'
        pw = 'test1234'
        conn.starttls()
        conn.login(un, pw)
        conn.sendmail('user@domain.com', recipients, message.as_string())
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll review this when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I fixed this issue now. Here is my code -

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import datetime

def sendMail():
    message = MIMEMultipart()   
    message["To"] = "xxxxx@xxxx.com,yyyy@yyyy.com"
    message["Cc"] = "zzzzzz@gmail.com,*********@gmail.com"
    message["From"] = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
    message["Password"] = "***************"
    server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'

    try:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        message['Subject'] = "cxxdRL Table status (Super Important Message) - "+str(now)
        server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(message["From"], message["Password"])
        server.sendmail(message["From"], message["To"].split(",") + message["Cc"].split(","), message.as_string())
        server.quit()
        print('Mail sent')
    except:
        print('Something went wrong...')

sendMail()
```