# How to add multiple recipients to this email code?

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtp, mime-types, smtplib

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

fromaddr = "YOUR EMAIL"
toaddr = ["FISRT EMAIL ADDRESS YOU SEND TO", "SECOND EMAIL ADDRESS YOU SEND TO"]

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "SUBJECT OF THE EMAIL"

body = "TEXT YOU WANT TO SEND"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = "NAME OF THE FILE WITH ITS EXTENSION"
attachment = open("PATH OF THE FILE", "rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "YOUR PASSWORD")
```

this is where i get an errot saying that a list element cannot be encoded
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027201/email-multiple-recipients-python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple recipients in email then you should fetch user from database and add in to the loop.

import System.Net;

import System.Net.Mail;

1. Fetch the user data based on your condition.
    `enter code here`var data = dataContext.website_request_logs.Where("condition");// we use datacontext to fetch data from website_request_logs table.
2. `foreach (website_request_log item in data)
       string EmailTo = item.email;
       string EmailFrom = item.fromEmail;
       string EmailSubject = item.emailSubject;`
3. `EmailUser(EmailTo ,EmailFrom ,EmailSubject );// call the function and send parameter in this.`

4.// we can use Email helper class to send email.

`private void EmailUser
            (
                               string EmailTo,
                               string EmailFrom,
                               string EmailSubject
             )
        {

```
         EmailHelper.SendEmail
                    (EmailFrom,
                    EmailTo,
                   EmailSubject,
                   );



    }`
```

5. SendEmail(){MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
   msg.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail, fromName);

   mail.Send(msg);

}